# Caps in sql field names with Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

It appears mysql table field names could be capped or not capped. I am working with another colleagues table and it appears the field names are capped whcih means I need to use all caps in Laravel too. Is there any way to work around this ... ?

For instance, my `images` table has an `id` field and his `images` table has `IMG_ID` as the field name so I have to use caps or rename all the fields?!

The result is that if I get an image object from his DB I have to do `$image->IMG_ID` or things don't work. I prefer not to use caps.

Just to be clear, if I do `ImagesClassName::where('img_id', $someId)` it works just fine. It doesn't work if I later do `$someImage->img_id;`
Not sure if this is intended behavior or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this intended behaviour. When you use:

```
ImagesClassName::where('img_id', $someId)
```

it will go to MySQL query and for MySQL caps for column names aren't important.

On contrary Eloquent set properties based on columns from table in Database. So if you have column `IMG_ID` in your table to access property you need to use `$someImage->IMG_ID` and not `$someImage->img_id` or `$someImage->img_ID` because only the first one (exact column name) will work.

Exactly the same is for relations. You should use everywhere the same case otherwise you may load them many times.

In case if you want to have column  with name `IMG_ID` and access it and set using `img_id` you could probably create [accessor and mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for this new property and then you could use lowercase that operate on uppercase column.

Comment: Thanks I will work to convince my colleagues caps are a bad idea for everything outside of CONSTANTS in oop and macros in C.